# How many hypercubes can be adjacent?

Tags: geometry

2D grid of squares, one square is surrounded by 8 others. 3D grid of cubes, one cube is surrounded by 26 others.

What is this number for 4D? Is there a general formula?

The tricky thing is diagonals. In 2D there are only pure corner diagonals. In 3D there are edge diagonals and pure corner diagonals. I suspect that in 4D, some new kind of diagonal will be there. But I want to include all classes of diagonals in my definition.

Comment: Hint: the main square in each case is the center of a $3\times 3$ square, the cube is the center of a $3\times3\times 3$ cube, etc

Comment: @XanderHenderson why is the tag of 4D "doing more harm than good"? This is clearly a question regarding 4-dimensional geometry. I cannot understand why the 4D tag would not apply.

Comment: @DrZ214 Tags are meant to help organize the site.  You created a brand new tag by tagging your question with [tag:4d] (which, by the way, is considered a *faux pas* on this site---typically, it is best to bring up new tag suggestions on meta before creating a new tag), which indicates that your question isn't getting lumped in with other questions about four dimensional geometry.  There is a [tag:3d] tag, which is relatively active, but no other "$n$d" tags.  I don't see this tag as being of any real utility to the site; rather, it causes clutter.  This is not the intention of tagging.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29718/tag-management-2019 ; It appears that this post has been discussed there, too.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I see. I did not realize i created a new tag. If it is super unpopular then i guess go ahead and delete it. I am still surprised tho that hyper-geometry does not have some tag. I woulda thought it a fairly common tag as i know ive seen many questions regarding shapes in 4 or more dimensions.

Comment: @DrZ214 I'm not sure that I see the point of a tag beyond [tag:geometry].  From the point of view of Euclidean geometry (which might, maybe, also be an appropriate tag here), things aren't really all that different from one dimension to another, and the differences usually involves other parts of mathematics, such as measure theory, linear algebra, or abstract algebra.  In any event, I can see an argument for a "higher-dimensional-geometry" tag (maybe).  Perhaps you should suggest it on meta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An $n$-cube is bounded by two codimension $1$ faces perpendicular to each of $n$ axes.  To count the number of codimension $k$ intersections of these faces we need to choose $k$ axes and then choose which of the two faces perpendicular to each of those axes to intersect. This gives $\binom{n}{k}2^k$ codimension $k$ subparts (intersection $k$ of the faces).

For example, a $3$-cube has $\binom{3}{3}2^3=8$ vertices (codimension $3$), $\binom{3}{2}2^2=12$ edges (codimension $2$), and $\binom{3}{1}2^1=6$ faces (codimension $1$).

For $1\le k\le n$, an $n$-cube shares a unique codimension $k$ subpart with each adjacent neighbor.

Thus, there are
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}2^k=3^n-1
$$
adjacent $n$-cubes.

Comment: I am not sure why the downvote was cast, but I did note that $k\lt n$ should be changed to $1\le k\le n$. Was there some other problem?